# Quotient by kernel of a character

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $\chi$ a linear character of $G$.

I've read that the quotient $G/ker(\chi)$ is cyclic. **Why is this true?**

I also wonder about the quotient if $\chi$ is not linear.

Comment: What do you mean by saying $\chi$ is not linear?

Comment: $\chi$ is linear if its degree (dimension) is $1$, not linear if it is $>1$

Comment: Usually, "linear representation" or "representation" refers to a homomorphism of $G$ into some $\operatorname{GL}(V)$, and "character" or "linear character" means $\operatorname{Dim}V=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $k$ is a field, then every finite subgroup of $k^{\ast}$ is cyclic.

For representations $(\rho,V)$ of $G$ of degree $>1$, the quotient $G/\operatorname{Ker}\rho$ can be isomorphic to *any* given finite group.  This is because the symmetric group on $n$ elements is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n$.

Comment: I see. Then for a representation of fixed degree $n$, $G/ker\rho$ can be isomorphic to any subgroup of $GL_n$?

Comment: Yes, take $G$ to be the given finite subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n$, and $\rho$ to be the inclusion map.